# How to display max and min numbers from a list?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int sum = 0; 
int inputNum;
int counter;
float average;
double maxMax = 0; 
double maxMin = 100;      

Scanner NumScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner charScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the total number of exams you want a average");
counter = NumScanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter " + counter + " numbers:");

for(int i = 1; i<=counter ;i++){          
    inputNum = NumScanner.nextInt();
    sum = sum + inputNum;
    System.out.println();
}

 average = sum / counter;
 System.out.println("The average of the " + counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);
}
```

I need help either putting a `if`-`else` statement in this loop to print out the max and min values from the list of numbers that were entered for the average, also I need to make sure the numbers are not less than 0 and greater than 100. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please let us know. Why would you print out max/min numbers inside the loop? You don't know what the maximum/minimum is unless you've looked at all numbers?

Comment: Read Collections class Javadoc

Comment: @SirRichie: it is. Look at his other questions/homework dumps for verification. Quit dumping your homework on this site. That's not how you learn.

Comment: Sadly, enough people posted answers instead of guidance towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using `if` statements and also using `max` and `min` variables to keep track of which numbers are the largest and smallest. This will check if the number is also equal to 0 or 100; if you don't want that just change the `101` to a `100` and the `-1` to a `0`.

```
int max = 0;
int min = 101;
for(int i = 1; i<=counter ;i++){          
    inputNum = NumScanner.nextInt();
    if(inputNum > max){
        max = inputNum;
    }
    if(inputNum < min){
        min = inputNum;
    }
    if(inputNum > -1 && inputNum < 101){
        sum = sum + inputNum;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You entered a number that wasn't in the range of 0 to 100");
    }
}

 average = sum / counter;
 System.out.println("The average of the " + counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);
```

Comment: This solution worked correctly I added this code in between the else statement and the average to print out the max and min values I wanted: // Print out of max and min exam grades//
          System.out.println( "Max Exam Score = " + Max );
          System.out.println( "Minimum Exam Score = " + Min );

      // Print out of average exam score//    
          average = sum / counter;
          System.out.println("The average of the " + counter + " exams you entered is " + average);

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an `if` statement or the `min` and `max` functions of `Math` for the min & max. The 0-100 check is an `if`.

```
// first define some variables
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // everything is smaller than this
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // opposite of above
for (...){
    // read your number as you currently do

    // 0-100 check
    if (inputNum < 0 || inputNum > 100){
        // error, do something like force the user to
        // enter a new number
    }

    // now add to the sum

    // the if way:
    if (inputNum < min) min = inputNum; 
    if (inputNum > max) max = inputNum;
    // the Math way:
    min = Math.min(min, inputNum);
    max = Math.max(max, inputNum);
}
// min and max are now in the variables
```

Answer (score 0):

For each number entered, check if it's >=0 or <= 100. That's one if inside the loop. As for min/max: you can keep track of the `currentMin` and `currentMax` found so far, in two `ints`, and update them if a new number that's smaller than the `currentMin` or larger than the `currentMax` pop up.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it's between 0 and 100 just add this line: if(inputNum > maxMax && inputNum

```
for(int i = 1; i<=counter ;i++){          
    inputNum = NumScanner.nextInt();
    if(inputNum > maxMax && inputNum <maxMin){
        sum = sum + inputNum;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now it only adds the number to sum if it's between 0-100.

Why do you want the lowest acceptable number to be called maxMax btw?

Answer (score 0):

Do below things.
1. Declare two variable "max" and "min" before for loop.
2. Add below conditional statement within for loop.

```
if (inputNum > max)
{
max = inputNum;
}
else if(inputNum < min)
{
min = inputNum
}
```